# I can access my heroku app live but my friends see only white blank page?

Tags: reactjs, redux

please check my app - https://real-estate-web-app.herokuapp.com

the app is accessible in chrome only I open the app with another browser it shows me a white blank page.

and please share the solution.

I tried all online solutions but no help

I want to share the app with the client and my friends for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open up the app in both Chrome and Firefox, loading just fine. Only thing I noticed was something odd with the Google Map API's, message about it receiving too many calls to the API. Also I believe by default Heroku has a "sleep" type setting, so the page doesn't stay loaded if the URL hasn't been visited recently; basically it pings the server and tells it to wake back up and then process the request and load the app. This may result in like a 10-15 second load time the first time hitting the page.